# select statement times out

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, settimeout

I need to populate dropdown menues with a table that contains 4 million rows.

> How can I do this without having it time out on the select statement?

Is need SQL Injections. ? or anything else ?

Now I tried only get top 100 rows . But my project have lot of users and lot of details in database . So i need to show all values in dropdownlist , my current code is here :

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       var search = YourSeachTextBox.Text.Trim();

       if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && search.Length > 3)
       {

             using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
             {

                   var query = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [YourTable] WHERE UserName LIKE @Search";


                   SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query,sqlConnection);


                   sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", search + "%");


             }
       }
}
```

Comment: Huh? You want to populate a dropdown with 4 million items? Good luck. Even if you could, nobody wants to select something from such a huge list.

Comment: Yes, you need SQL injections :)

Comment: It can't be done without SQL injections

Comment: For facebook and other social network has lot of users , How can manage that ? they also used sql injection ? or anything other way's ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter :--)  did you see the facebook search friends option ? this same functionality wants to be me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that you intend to populate drop downs with parts aof 4 million rows?
Then you do have to create indexes on those columns that help to separate them!

If you really intend to populate them with most of the contents at once, things will have to timeout for sure as your clients browsers won't get to handle this!

Comment: How index will help to fetch all rows from database ?

Comment: @Anton thats why i wrote i assume he intended to choose only some of them! What kind of sense would 4 Million OPTION-Items make?